# How to position element just beyond the left edge of the viewport?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have an element whose width is either a fixed `px` value or a percentage. I want the right side of its bounding box to be at *x* coordinate −1 of the screen (or viewport), so its right side is touching the left side of the screen — the element would become invisible by this.

Is there a value I can use for the CSS `right` or `left` property that works for both percentages and fixed `px` widths or is there some other way to achieve this?

Comment: show relevant code of what you've attempted, preferably with a jsfiddle/stack snippet

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This set of CSS rules works for that:

```css
/* These rules position the element just beyond the left edge of the viewport. */
.positioned {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

/* You can open your developer tools (Right Click → Inspect Element) and change the `-100%` from above to see this box. */
.positioned {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  padding: 4px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="positioned">
  I’m on the left.
</div>
```

`position: absolute` and `left: 0` place the element at the left edge, but within the viewport. Then [`transform: translateX(-100%)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Browser_compatibility) is the rule that moves your element to the left exactly by its width.

This works because, if the arguments of `translate`, `translateX`, or `translateY` are percentages, then these percentages relate to the *element’s* width and height. In the case of other properties like `left` or `right`, they relate to the *parent’s* width and height. Therefore, `left` and `right` cannot be used in all circumstances for this — relative or fixed width —, which is why the answer to your original question is: *no, there is no value for those two properties to achieve this*. There may be some form of trickery to achieve this, but CSS3’s `transform` functions (or individual — albeit less compatible — properties) make this easy.

---

If you run the snippet you should see *nothing*. If you use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and inspect the result of the snippet and find the `<div class="positioned">`, you’ll see this:

[image: The bounding box of the <div> can be seen just to the left of the snippet result.]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 1em;
    left: 1em;
}
```

Comment: This fits the title of the question, but not the description that the object should be hiding off the left hand side of the screen.